# mosquitto subscribe to test broker: Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to subscribe to http://test.mosquitto.org/ with the following command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -t "#" -v
```

When doing so, it first says nothing and  after a few minutes it prints `Error: Network is unreachable`. To make sure I also tried to subscribe to https://iot.eclipse.org/ and also tried to use the ip instead of the DNS name of the broker.

Does anybody know how I can subscribe to the broker?

**EDIT:** I can ping test.mosquitto.org

Comment: Where are you running this all from, what network are you connected to? Could you be behind a firewall that is blocking port 1883? You didn't say if connecting to iot.eclipse.org worked, just that you tried

Comment: @hardillb connecting to iot.eclipse.org and also to broker.hivemq.com didn't work either. How can I check if the port is blocked?

Comment: You will need to talk to your network administrator

Answer (score 0):

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -t "#" -v
```

> When doing so, it first says nothing and after a few minutes it prints
>   Error: Network is unreachable

seems like dns is isn’t resolved, to test check the dns is resolved first simple test would be to do a ping,

```
ping test.mosquitto.org
```

If its reachable it should print out following:

```
ping test.mosquitto.org
PING test.mosquitto.org (37.187.106.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ks.ral.me (37.187.106.16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from ks.ral.me (37.187.106.16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=15.3 ms
^C
--- test.mosquitto.org ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.311/15.393/15.476/0.148 ms
```

Once dns is resolved following should work without any errors:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -t "#" -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I can ping test.mosquitto.org but still can't subscribe

Comment: could you post the logs from file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log, and also the conf file (/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf), make sure  (mosquitto) is running.

Comment: Those logs and config would be meaningless as this is the client connecting to a remote broker, so no need to be running a local broker

Comment: @Katharina, can you check your networks proxy settings to see if that is blocking. and also check netstat -plut (for port 1883)